# why we use MAX aggregate or aggregate functions in CASE statement clause in SQL

Tags: sql

Why we use them with column type string?

Like this code:

```
SELECT 
    event_id, 
    event_time,  
    user_id, 
    platform,  
    MAX(CASE WHEN parameter_name = 'item_id'
                THEN CAST(parameter_value AS INT)
                ELSE NULL
        END)  AS item_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN parameter_name = 'referrer'
                THEN parameter_value
                ELSE NULL
        END)  AS referrer
FROM 
    dsv1069.events
WHERE 
    event_name  = 'view_item'
GROUP BY 
    event_id, event_time, user_id, platform
ORDER BY 
    event_id
```

Comment: Could you explain your question, with a simpler example?

Answer (score 1):

Max, min works even on String and we use it to to elimintae NULLs because aggregate functions dont consider NULLs

Answer (score 1):

You need an aggregation function on the `CASE` expression in order for the query to parse correctly.  That is required.

Some databases support `ANY()` or `ANY_VALUE()` as an aggregation function.

If you are expecting one value, then `STRING_AGG()`/`LIST_AGG()`/`ARRAY_AGG()` are overkill.

So, the most convenient are `MIN()` and `MAX()` because they work on almost any data tyep.